# Dell H200 RAID controller + SATA drives

Tags: raid

I've bought a H200 hardware RAID controller to go into a Poweredge R210.

I've got two 2TB SATA drives to setup as a RAID1 array.

The question I have is:

Do I need to connect the SATA drives to the H200 via the on-board SAS ports, or can I continue to use the SATA ports on the motherboard? If I need to use the SAS ports on the controller, will standard SAS cables work and will this cable also power the drives?

Answer (score 2):

Is this serious or are you trolling us?

If you need the H200 to create the R1 array then yes, yes they need to connect to it.

We can't answer your cabling questions without knowing the exact make and model of drive, but if they're from Dell then they should just plug into the external drive slots and then the drive backplane connects to the H200.

Comment: The R210 doesn't have external drive slots - the sata drives sit inside caddy's and have power connectors and SATA cables into the motherboard. The drives I'll be using are 2TB Seagate ST2000DM008 BarraCuda